# Python - Enviar csv para banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, python-3.x, csv

Estou escrevendo um *script* que junta todos arquivos de um mesmo formato em uma pasta e cria um CSV único e desejo mandar esse CSV para o banco de dados. Como novos arquivos vão entrando nessa pasta, o CSV sempre vai criando novas linhas.

No entanto, estou usando esse comando para enviar os arquivos para o banco..

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="",database="",user="",password="")

cur = conn.cursor()
with open('extratos.csv', 'r') as f:

        cur.copy_from(f, 'extratos', sep=',')

        conn.commit()
```

Mas toda vez que o *script* roda ele lê o arquivo CSV do início e acusa que a primeira linha já se encontra no banco de dados. Como faço pra ele enviar apenas as novas linhas inseridas?

Comment: Não conseguiria fazer esse script buscar apenas os CSVs que ainda não foram processados?

Comment: Coloque uma parte do arquivos CSV para ilustrar a sua estrutura.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, o CSV é único. Ele junta todos os arquivos ofx em um único CSV